# IdentityServer4: Show error message during external login

Tags: identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer4 with several external login providers, like Google and Facebook. If a user logs in using one of these external providers, I'll try to retrieve the user from a database, based on the email address. Users might be flagged as blocked or resigned in our database. If this is the case, I need to show an error message to the user. I also need to redirect back to the login page, to give the user the option to login with a different account.

I'm using the [ExternalController of the IdentityServer4 Quickstart](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/master/Quickstart/Account/ExternalController.cs). This example only throws exceptions, but doesn't provide an example on how to display an error message to the user.

In IdentityServer3, `IUserService.AuthenticateExternalAsync` provided the option to return an `AuthenticateResult` with an error message:

```
context.AuthenticateResult = new AuthenticateResult("Error message");
```

Is there something similar available in IdentityServer4 for external logins?

Comment: ExternalController is a starting point for the developer to modify.  If you don't want it to throw an exception on authentication failure then change `public async Task<IActionResult> Callback()` to return an `IActionResult` to display an error message and redirect back to the login page.

Comment: @Richard how can I redirect to the login page? Somehow I need to stay in the same login context.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said redirect back to your application's url. Your application will detect that the user is not authenticated and will redirect to the login page.